# Trying to pull from a folder of images

Tags: javascript, html

Hi first time here and I'm very new to coding

I'm making a website where its kind of an inside joke about nfts (making fun of them just wanted to be clear)

and I got a bunch of randomly generated images that I want to be selected from to show one at random when you click a button

right now I have this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ImageArray = new Array();
    ImageArray[0] = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516499862863892/55.png";
    ImageArray[1] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516499531522128/52.png';
    ImageArray[2] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516499208548432/54.png';
    ImageArray[3] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516498898173962/32.png';
    ImageArray[4] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516498617171988/44.png';
    ImageArray[5] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516498390659082/47.png';
    ImageArray[6] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516498138988554/27.png';
    ImageArray[7] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516497883152414/11.png';
    ImageArray[8] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516497686036520/5.png';
    ImageArray[9] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912516497459535882/3.png';
    ImageArray[10] = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/669350505264447512/912517257987518484/70.png';

function getRandomImage() {
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);
    var img = ImageArray[num];
    document.getElementById("randImage").innerHTML = ('<img  src="' + img + '" width="300px,">')

}
</script>
<button onclick="getRandomImage()";>NFT</button>
<div class="parent" id="randImage" ></div>"
```

and that works pretty well but I don't want to write ImageArray 1 to 100 for every possible image and was wondering if I could somehow write it to where it pulls from a file of all the images

help would be appreciated and also explain as much as possible because I would like to know how to do similar stuff

https://misinformedmember.000webhostapp.com/

above is the website if it helps

Comment: You would need to have a mapping of some sort, and would have to write out 100 links in *some form*, as there doesn't seem to be a pattern to the URLs. In addition to this, please don't use 000Webhost; [they store passwords in plaintext](https://www.troyhunt.com/breaches-traders-plain-text-passwords/).

Comment: thank you for your answer and the heads up I'm going to go take it down and try to find somewhere else to host it or wait until I can afford a .com